# What does bracket and comma do in find?

Tags: find

It is confusing me when I see some bracket and comma show on the script. I can't really understand how does it make it. For example

`find /work \( -fprint /dev/stderr \) , \( -name 'core' -exec rm {} \; \)`

Question:-
-what does bracket do? 
-what does comma do?
-where can I get this manual about bracket and comma keyword in bash.

Comment: Look up `man find` on your computer. Or checkout the [man pages on the web](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/find.1.php).

Comment: All these brackets are escaped (preceded by a \ character) so bash sends them through to find, right? So asking find what it does with brackets is the Q

Comment: Fixed the question title and tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses/brackets are used by `find` to enforce precedence among its predicates. The comma is an operator in GNU `find` that evaluates both the preceding predicate and the predicate that follows, but ignores the result of the first. In your command

```
find /work \( -fprint /dev/stderr \) , \( -name 'core' -exec rm {} \; \)
```

you have two (compound) predicates:

- `-fprintf /dev/stderr`
- `-name 'core' -exec rm {} \;`

The first one prints the name of the found file to standard error. The second one removes only those files whose name is `core`. Without the comma, only the names of the file being removed would be written to standard output; that is, the comma overrides the implicit `and` performed on multiple predicates. (The parentheses around the `-fprintf` might be optional, since they are just forming a group consisting of a single predicate, but I'm not positive.)

Comment: As you said, The first one prints the name of the found file to standard error, then which keyword for display the list to screen?

Comment: If you absolutely, positively, must write to the screen, use `/dev/tty`. However, it is usually better to write to `/dev/stderr` (for errors) or `/dev/stdout` (for actual output), and let the user of the command decide whether those file descriptors should point to the terminal or some other file or pipeline. On startup, your shell's standard output and error are bound to the terminal/screen, and any programs started by the shell inherit those same file descriptors, unless explicitly changed.

Answer (score 2):

`(` and `)` are used in bash to execute one or more commands in a sub-shell. You can find more on that topic at http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html.

However, in the command that you have posted, they are not used by `bash` since they are escaped -- you are using `\(` instead of just `(`. As a result, `(` and `)` are passed to `find` as its arguments. Also note that `;` is also escaped since it has special meaning in `bash`. As far as `find` is concerned, it sees the following arguments:

```
/work ( -fprint /dev/stderr ) , ( -name 'core' -exec rm {} ; )
```

The comma (`,`) is part of the `find` command. `bash` does nothing with it.

Comment: Let me guess, it means find whatever in the 'work' directory and fprint it to /dev/stderr, meanwhile it will remove the file which contain 'core' in the file content?

Comment: The first part is right. The second part means remove all the files that are named (that's what the flag `-name` stands for) `core` under `/work` or any of its sub-directories.

Comment: -1. None of the parentheses in this question are processed by `bash` (they are used for grouping by `find`), and `(...)` and `$(...)` are two distinct constructs in `bash` (although the second does incidentally spawn a subshell).

Comment: @chepner I updated the answer to address the points you raised. Thanks for helping to get the answer in a better shape.